# mix blend mode or invert filter to achieve oppposite colors?

Tags: html, css

I know there are similar questions but I have not found a solution for my question.
I am trying to achieve the following effect:
[image: proposed layout design]

Solutions I've seen for something similar have been with black on white. I would like to use colors siilar to the image below.
I've tried using mix blend mode and invert filters in the css but can't get the desired result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here is my code:

```js
progress(100, 150, $('#progressBar'));


function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {

  var progressBarWidth = (timeleft / timetotal) * $element.width();


    $element.find('div.bar').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 1000, "linear");
    if(timeleft > 0) {  
        setTimeout(function() {
            progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
        }, 1000);
    }

var date = new Date(null);
date.setSeconds(timeleft);
var timeString = date.toISOString().substr(11, 8);
var newtimeleft = timeString

  $('#timer').text(newtimeleft)
}
```

```css
#progressBar {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #B8C3C3;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 1;
  filter: invert(100%);
}

#progressBar .bar {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 0;
  background-color: #4B5863;
}

#timer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 99999;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: "Manrope";
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="progressBar">
  <div class="bar">
  </div>
  <div id="timer">
  </div>
</div>
```

the 'startDate' and 'endDate' need to be changed accordingly so the progress bar can be seen moving behind the numbers. (ie set a samll time difference between the dates)

Comment: Please post code with your attempt so we don't have to start from scratch. I would try creating the div containing the numbers twice with their respective coloring and background. Then give the one above overflow: hidden; and assign a width to let the div below show.

Comment: @PeterPointer I edited my question and added my code. I can get close to the effect by adding mix-blend-mode but have no control over the colors

Comment: Good thanks! I changed your code into a runnable snippet (the `<>` button). Assuming it uses jQuery, so I added jquery 3.7.1. Please change if not appropriate. Maybe just make start and end date automatic so the example shows the effect?

Comment: Thanks @PeterPointer. Edited the code as requested

Comment: This looks good to me, but of course with filter: invert you'll have to choose the original colors so that they look intended when they're inverted. The [can I use filter: invert](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_types_filter-function_invert) comparison also shows no direct problem from the browser side. Maybe someone else can help.

Comment: Appreciate the help. If anyone has any other suggestions that would be aweseom. I'm at a dead end for this at the moment.